# How to position vertically a repeat-y image background?

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I have this code:

```
background:url("someimage.gif") repeat-y 50px right;
```

the problem here is that I need the background to start 50px from top so there is a 50px space between the image and the top but that wont happen. I know very well that the image would position right if not repeated but I need it to be repeated vertically. Is there any way around? How can I achieve that space between top and the start of the repeated image?

Comment: No...`repeat-y` means just that.. *in both directions...up and down*.

Comment: What would be in the top 50px?

Comment: Essential Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417501/multiple-background-images-positioning?rq=1

Comment: nothing, just a blank space

Answer (score 0):

There a way to fake it if there is nothing in that top space.

Apply 50px (or your chosen value) of `padding-top` to the div.

The apply the background as usual (`repeat-y`) but *clip* the background to the `content-box`of the div.

[**Background-clip @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

```css
div {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/50/50) repeat-y;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 50vh;
  background-clip: content-box;
  width:50vw;
  margin:2em auto;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**OR**

Use a position pseudo-element suitably sized/positioned

```css
div {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/50/50) repeat-y;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem with that is that the content will also be pushed down and I dont want that.

Comment: Because you are adding padding to the container which will push the content down. I want to push down only the background, not the content.

Comment: After all, seems like the pseudo-element answer is the only option possible here. I think I will stick to that. Thank you.